# how to play slideshare presentations using html5 player and slideshare API?

Tags: html, slideshow, swfobject

I am using slideshare player api http://www.slideshare.net/developers/playerapi  to embed player in to my web application but it is embedding flash player and which is not playing on mobile devices(ipad). how can I get html5 player from slideshare?

Answer (score 0):

SlideShare now has a HTML5 player, probably it's new judging by the time of your question and my current experience with it's oEmbed implementation.

It's still confusing though because I'm not able to find proper documentation on the new player.

I hope they update this soon.